# Does fstat require disk access on Linux/ext4?

Tags: linux, files, filesystems, linux-kernel, c

`Linux Kernel 5.3`

Consider the `fstat` syscall defined as `int fstat(int fd, struct stat *statbuf);`. **Is disk access required for the `fstat` syscall on ext4?**

I did some research related to it and find out some info. The in-kernel entry point to the system call is the function [`vfs_statx_fd`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3/source/fs/stat.c#L134). Here is how its implementation looks like:

```
int vfs_statx_fd(unsigned int fd, struct kstat *stat,
         u32 request_mask, unsigned int query_flags)
{
    struct fd f;
    int error = -EBADF;

    if (query_flags & ~KSTAT_QUERY_FLAGS)
        return -EINVAL;

    f = fdget_raw(fd);
    if (f.file) {
        error = vfs_getattr(&f.file->f_path, stat,
                    request_mask, query_flags);
        fdput(f);
    }
    return error;
}
```

So what we have here is that the `unsigned int fd` which is actual file descriptor that a user passed to the system call is used to find a pointer to the [`struct file`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3/source/include/linux/fs.h#L922). The crucial part of its definition is

```
struct file {
    //...
    struct path     f_path;
    struct inode        *f_inode;   /* cached value */
    //...
}
```

So we basically have that `struct file` represents an opened file and the struct contains references to `dentry` and `inode`

**Is it true that in case we have an opened file descriptor we can get all the stats just from memory avoiding costly disk access?**

*Update*: I tried to flush Kernel caches with `free && sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && free` right before invoking the `syscall` and it did not affect the timing of stat syscall. So I tend to think that no disk access is required.

Comment: fstat crashed my command-not-found addition to bash....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On an Ext4 file system, the function graph starting from `vfs_statx_fd` is

```
 0)               |  vfs_statx_fd() {
 0)               |    __fdget_raw() {
 0)   0.225 us    |      __fget_light();
 0)   0.775 us    |    }
 0)               |    vfs_getattr() {
 0)               |      security_inode_getattr() {
 0)               |        selinux_inode_getattr() {
 0)               |          __inode_security_revalidate() {
 0)               |            _cond_resched() {
 0)   0.216 us    |              rcu_all_qs();
 0)   0.575 us    |            }
 0)   0.945 us    |          }
 0)               |          inode_has_perm() {
 0)   0.356 us    |            avc_has_perm();
 0)   0.709 us    |          }
 0)   2.223 us    |        }
 0)   2.808 us    |      }
 0)               |      vfs_getattr_nosec() {
 0)               |        ext4_file_getattr() {
 0)               |          ext4_getattr() {
 0)   0.203 us    |            generic_fillattr();
 0)   0.600 us    |          }
 0)   1.040 us    |        }
 0)   1.502 us    |      }
 0)   4.854 us    |    }
 0)   6.913 us    |  }
```

Looking at the implementations of all these functions shows that there’s no provision for disk I/O. As you surmise, the data comes from the cached inode.

See also [the `fstat(2)` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) which mentions that:

> *Note*: for performance and simplicity reasons, different fields in the
>          `stat` structure may contain state information from different moments
>          during the execution of the system call.  For example, if `st_mode` or
>          `st_uid` is changed by another process by calling [`chmod(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chmod.2.html) or [`chown(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chown.2.html),
>          `stat()` might return the old `st_mode` together with the new `st_uid`, or
>          the old `st_uid` together with the new `st_mode`.

(although this has more to do with locking than caching).

With some other file systems, `AT_STATX_FORCE_SYNC` can be included in the query flags to force a remote sync; this is supported on Ceph, FUSE, NFS, and VirtualBox guest shared folders.

Comment: Thanks much. Interestingly, the `stat(const char *, struct stat*)` operates with a path. So it should do some sort of disk-I/O in case of clean caches. It's entry point is [vfs_statx](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3/source/fs/stat.c#L168). I thought that `user_path_at(dfd, filename, lookup_flags, &path);` line should be responsible for disk access, but it is not clear how it goes to `ext4`-related kernel code (I didn't catch). Do you know how the lookup does disk-I/O in case the `dentry` is not cached? I checked call stacks with `perf record`, but it does not appear in the report.